# How does sqlite synchronize page cache among different processes?

Tags: sqlite, multiprocess

I know sqlite is using cache pages within the process to speed up read performance, also, sqlite allows multi-processes to access the same sqlite database file by applying file-level lock mechanism. My question is: if process A updated page x, in the meantime process B had a cached of page X, will process B read stalled value or there is mechanic to notify process B of the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) of the database file format:

> The file change counter is a 4-byte big-endian integer at offset 24 that is incremented whenever the database file is unlocked after having been modified. When two or more processes are reading the same database file, each process can detect database changes from other processes by monitoring the change counter. A process will normally want to flush its database page cache when another process modified the database, since the cache has become stale. The file change counter facilitates this.

So, yes, there's a way to notify other connections when one modifies the database so they can invalidate their caches.